# How can I use Image.getSize for all items in an array, on component load?

Tags: image, react-native, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm trying to full width (and proportionately) display an image, so I need to get the height to then determine the aspect ratio, to then determine the new height for an array of images. Image.getSize seems like it's the best way to get the width and height, but I can't seem to come up with a safe and efficient way to get all of the dimensions.

In the below code, postImages gets an array of image urls, I'm then running useEffect to check if that exists, and then looping through the array.

My concerns are how to effectively take the height and width. Currently this takes an extremely long time and in console I can see the console.log indefinitely (the "this continues to run repeatedly line below").

Is there a better way to use this Image.getSize function? Should I not have it in useEffect? Is there a better way to update this array of images' width and heights?

```
export default posts = (props) => {
  let { post } = props
  let { postImages = [] } = post
  const [images, setImages] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    let images = []
    if(postImages){
      postImages.map((img) => {
        Image.getSize(
              img,
              (width, height) => {
                console.log("this continues to run repeatedly")
                setImages([...images, { url: img, width, height }])
              }
            );
      }, [postImages]);
    }
  })
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: using const images and then let images in useEffect hook looks suspicious

Answer (score 0):

Do you need `useState` and `useEffect` there? As far as I understood from the question, you wanted to get an array of images with their sizes depending on props, so is there any need to store them?

```
  export default posts = (props) => {
      let { post } = props
      let { postImages = [] } = post
    
      const images = []
      if(postImages) {
        postImages.map((img) => ({
          Image.getSize(
                img, (width, height) => {
                  console.log("this continues to run repeatedly on props change")
                  s.push({ url: img, width, height })
                })
        })
      }
  }
```